# Can't add stylesheet to Django Admin

Tags: django

I am trying to overide the default Django admin styles.
I created a new app 'theme', placed it before Django Admin in INSTALLED_APPS and it works. Then I copied over base_site from the Django GitHub repo under Admin. I then added a custom style sheet which I am unable to link to.

Here is what my 'theme' app looks like:

```
├── __init__.py
├── static
│   └── admin
│       └── css
│           └── ross.css
└── templates
    └── admin
        └── base_site.html
```

I cannot link to my stylesheet without getting a 404.

```
{% block extrastyle %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/ross.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to restart the Django dev server, then it worked...

Comment: That is the complete answer, restart the dev server